# Floyd's cycle detection algorithm, why is it linear time, and how do you prove that tortoise and hare will meet?

Tags: algorithms

I haven't been able to find a full proof of Floyd's cycle detection algorithm. All proofs that I have been able to find just explain why the distance from the start of the graph to the start of the cycle is equal to the distance that hasn't been traveled within the cycle.

But 1) how do we prove that tortoise and hare will meet inside the cycle? And 2) how do we prove that this algorithm is linear time?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd.27s_Tortoise_and_Hare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since hare moves 1 step faster than turtle, it will take him d steps to catch up with it, where d is the distance between them when turtle enters the loop, because this is akin to making turtle static and making hare move 1 step at a time. From that, it also follows that this algorithm is linear time and that there's no way that hare will miss turtle.